# AWS Cognito Group Management Limitations

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am writing a system monitoring tool that will collect metrics on user specified endpoints periodically using Lambda, store the results in Dynamo, and then allow users to fetch metrics through a react app that will call another Lambda instance to retrieve the data from Dynamo. Queries will ultimately be done against a UID that is assigned to each user specified monitor, that will do a query over a GSI of datetime and the monitorID.

I have been looking at Cognito to act as my user store. My goal is to have permissions defined on the monitor UID level to allow users to only have access to their monitor. I am looking at creating a group for each monitor which will then be assigned to the creating user. The group would then be in the JWT token Cognito provides on login, which would be used to authorize the Lambda invocation.

My questions are:

- Is this a sustainable model if thousands of monitors are created
  leading to thousands of groups within a userpool?
- If a user has access to hundreds of monitors, is there risk of the token size being obscenely large for this use case?
- Is there a hard or soft service limit I am theoretically going to run into, say with hudreds of users with say tens of monitors each?
- Finally, is this using Cognito in the intended fashion or are there more efficient approaches for fine grain user control?

**Note**: The main reason I came up with this model is it is stateless, fine grain, will not require a permission lookup for each query, and does not require the individual records to be authorization conscious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will exactly fit your use-case, but a very clean solution to fine-grained access is to leverage access policies based on the Cognito sub ID. For example, [here's the AWS doc for doing this with S3 prefixes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) so as to simulate a filesystem with user directories. E.g.

> ```
> {
>     "Sid": "ListYourObjects",
>     "Effect": "Allow",
>     "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
>     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
>     "Condition": {
>         "StringLike": {
>             "s3:prefix": ["cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
>         }
>     }
> },
> {
>     "Sid": "ReadWriteDeleteYourObjects",
>     "Effect": "Allow",
>     "Action": [
>         "s3:GetObject",
>         "s3:PutObject",
>         "s3:DeleteObject"
>     ],
>     "Resource": [
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
>     ]
> }
> ```

If you know a monitor should only ever be accessed by one user, and you can permission each monitor based on the Cognito sub ID, this may be the cleanest method for you.